# how to find where is located the file via include in django?

Tags: python, django

I have t‌wo urls:

```
url(r'^users/', include('apps.users.urls', namespace='users')),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

the first one `/users` I can see through the path `apps.users.urls` where is located, but the second one is not in the folders path, how can I know where is located the `allauth.urls`

Answer (score 0):

Once a package has been installed you can look up its information using pip show: `pip show django-allauth`